# Combine datetime2 and csvsimple

Tags: csvsimple, datetime2

How can I make the following code compile:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
a,b
2019,00:00:00
2019,00:00:01
2020,00:00:02
2018,00:00:03
2018,00:00:04
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\csvreader[head to column names,tabular=llllll]{test.csv}{}
{\a&\DTMtime{\b}}
\end{document}
```

Note that it does compile if I replace `\b` by `00:00:01`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\DTMtime` expects its argument to already be expanded. You can see the problem if you say:

```
\def\test{00:00:00}
\DTMtime{\test}
```

this already throws an error. You need to expand first `\test` and then run `\DTMtime` on it. One way to do this is by saying

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\DTMtime{\test}}\temp
```

The command `\edef` defines a new macro by recursively expanding the body of the macro. The command `\noexpand` stops `\DTMtime` from being expanded, so that `\temp` gets defined as `\DTMtime{00:00:00}` which then works as expected.

I like to define this inside of a macro, say called `\eval`:

```
\def\eval#1{\edef\temp{#1}\temp}
\eval{\noexpand\DTMtime{\test}}
```

Another option is to do this using Latex3. Latex3 defines the macro `\exp_args:Nx` which `\edef`'s the argument of a macro before calling it, so then `\exp_args:Nx\DTMtime{\test}` will expand `\test` first and then run `\DTMtime` on it. You can define a wrapper macro for `\DTMtime` that always expands its argument first. Here's sample code for that:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\DTMtimex { \exp_args:Nx\DTMtime }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\test{00:00:00}
\DTMtimex{\test}
\end{document}
```

Here's complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
a,b
2019,00:00:00
2019,00:00:01
2020,00:00:02
2018,00:00:03
2018,00:00:04
\end{filecontents*}

\def\eval#1{\edef\temp{#1}\temp}
\def\DTMtimex#1{\eval{\noexpand\DTMtime{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[head to column names,tabular=llllll]{test.csv}{}
{\a&\DTMtimex{\b}}
\end{document}
```